# class variable not keeping value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hello I have a class called tableClass that stores a double variable called totalHours. I would like to then put this variable in a readonly property. The problem is value for totalHours keeps reseting to 0 . Not sure if I'm declaring the variable wrong or what not, I also tried storing the value in viewstate and the same problem occurs. Any suggestions? Any questions let me know. Thank you!

table class

```
Public Class tableClass
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private TotalHours As Double = 0

    Private Sub AddNewRow(ByVal hrsTextBox as TextBox)

        TotalHours = TotalHours + CDbl(hrsTextBox.Text)
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property RegHours() As Double
        'Returns the total hours so far recorded
        Get
            Return TotalHours
        End Get
        End Property
   End Class
```

default

```
Protected Sub btnAddDate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        dim dateTable as New tableClass

        dateTable.AddNewRow(hrsTextbox)
End Sub

 Protected Sub HoursChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            LabelHoursTotal.Text = (dateTable.RegHours + CDbl(TextBoxHours.Text)).ToString
 End Sub
```

aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHours" runat="server" width ="90" Text = "0" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged ="HoursChange"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label id="lblHoursTotal" runat="server" Text = "0"></asp:Label>

<asp:Button ID="btnAddHour" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="btnAddHour_Click" />
```

Comment: Well, you've got a bit going on here. Step through with the debugger. What does `hrsTextBox.Text` contain? Did you confirm it is set to a value other than 0?

Comment: I don't see any use of ViewState in this code

Comment: Also, are you sure you are working with the same class instance? It is not a static class or property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the value somehow and when it comes to web applications, it's a good idea to either use ViewState or Session, depending on the situation and your needs. ViewState is specific to the page, Session is specific to the user.

Comment: Much better solution than mine.   Must be the cold medicine stuffing up my brain :)